# Order of numpy (logical_and vs '&') statements leads to different results

Tags: python, numpy, boolean, output

I have a simple piece of code where I am trying to compare the numpy function logical_and vs the "&" operator.

I encounter a very strange behavior where the order in the which the statements are executed, seem to have an effect on the final result when in fact they shouldn't. Weird!

In the below code , if I interchange the final_mask1 and final_mask statement order, it leads to a different value of the variable "test" as well as a different image as an output. This is for the case where I have final_mask as output. Am I missing something here? How can I resolve this? 
TIA

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import misc
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
photo_data = misc.imread('./sd-3layers.jpg')
red_mask = photo_data[:, : ,0] < 150
green_mask = photo_data[:, : ,1] > 100
blue_mask = photo_data[:, : ,2] < 100

final_mask1 = np.logical_and(red_mask, green_mask, blue_mask)
final_mask = red_mask & green_mask & blue_mask

test = (final_mask1 == final_mask)
print(np.all(test))
photo_data[final_mask] = 0
plt.figure(figsize=(15,15))
plt.imshow(photo_data)
```

Comment: Check the documentation of logical and. The third argument is the **out** argument.

Comment: Following up on @MSeifert's comment, `np.logical_and.reduce((red_mask, green_mask, blue_mask))` would do what you're expecting.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @fuglede make it an answer pls :) This question should be marked as answered.

Comment: @Y0da: Yeah, agreed, done

Answer (score 0):

Looking up [the documentation](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.logical_and.html) of `logical_and`, one finds that it compares only two arrays, and that the third argument is used for storing results in a different array. You can use `reduce` to avoid having to write to calls to `logical_and`, so what you're trying to do ends up looking like

```
np.logical_and.reduce((red_mask, green_mask, blue_mask))
```